# How does "Compare And Set" in AtomicInteger works

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile, compare-and-swap, atomicinteger

`AtomicInteger` works with two concepts : CAS and `volatile` variable.

Using `volatile` variable insures that the current value will be visible to all threads and it will not be cached.

But I am confused over CAS(compare AND set) concept which is explained below:

```
public final int getAndIncrement() {
    for (;;) {
        int current = get();
        int next = current + 1;
        if (compareAndSet(current, next))
            return current;
    }
 }
```

My question is that what`if(compareAndSet(current, next)` returns `false`? Will the value not be updated? 
In this case what will happen when a Thread is executing the below case:

```
private AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
count.incrementAndGet();
```

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2013-07-22/thread-safe-data-structures/

Comment: More complete explanation: https://www.baeldung.com/java-atomic-variables

Comment: The loop is there till the next value is have been successfully updated, but since java 8+ you can simply call getAndAdd(1), N.B just need to pass in the delta which is 1 here. No need to loop anymore, all taken care for  you by JDK. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#getAndAdd-int-

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The atomic objects make use of [Compare and Swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) mechanism to make them atomic - i.e. it is possible to guarantee that the value **was** as specified **and is now** at the new value.

The code you posted continually tries to set the current value to one more than it was before. Remember that another thread could also have performed a `get` and is trying to set it too. If two threads race each other to change the value it is possible for one of the increments to fail.

Consider the following scenario:

1. Thread 1 calls `get` and gets the value `1`.
2. Thread 1 calculates `next` to be `2`.
3. Thread 2 calls `get` and gets the value `1`.
4. Thread 2 calculates `next` to be `2`.
5. Both threads try to write the value.

Now because of atomics - **only one thread will succeed**, the other will recieve `false` from the `compareAndSet` and go around again.

If this mechanism was not used it would be quite possible for both threads to increment the value resulting in only one increment actually being done.

The confusing infinite loop `for(;;)` will only really loop if many threads are writing to the variable at the same time. Under very heavy load it may loop around several times but it should complete quite quickly.

Comment: But how? Both thread can Campare at same time, and then Swap at the same time. There should be some sort of blocking or waiting

Comment: compareAndSet atomicity is ensured on hardware level

Answer (score 10):

`for (;;)` is an infinite loop, so it will just retry the attempt.